# EC2 run-instances error: Invalid value ('Encrypted') for param element of list:BlockDeviceMappings of type list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

According to the AWS CLI documentation, I can specify that a volume should be encrypted and provide the KMS Key Id accordingly. I can't make it work though... what am I doing wrong here?

```
aws ec2 run-instances --block-device-mappings '[ {"DeviceName": "/dev/sda1", "Ebs": { "DeleteOnTermination": true, "VolumeSize": 10, "VolumeType": "gp2" }}, {"DeviceName": "/dev/sdb1", "Ebs": { "DeleteOnTermination": false, "VolumeSize": 20, "VolumeType": "gp2", "Encrypted": true, "KmsKeyId": "f80d1a0e-9295-4ca7-8f27-2ce79fec9838" }} ]' --image-id $BASE_AMI --count 1 --instance-type $INSTANCE_TYPE --security-group-ids $SEC_GROUPS --subnet-id $SUBNET --key-name "$KEY_PAIR"
```

Pretty-printed JSON for block-device-mappings below for ease of reference:

```
[
  {
    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
    "Ebs": {
      "DeleteOnTermination": true,
      "VolumeSize": 10,
      "VolumeType": "gp2"
    }
  },
  {
    "DeviceName": "/dev/sdb1",
    "Ebs": {
      "DeleteOnTermination": false,
      "VolumeSize": 20,
      "VolumeType": "gp2",
      "Encrypted": true,
      "KmsKeyId": "f80d1a0e-9295-4ca7-8f27-2ce79fec9838"
    }
  }
]
```

When I run the above command, I get the error you see in the subject line. If I swap the order of the Encrypted and KmsKeyId values around, it complains about KmsKeyId instead.

FWIW, I installed AWS CLI via apt on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
john@dev3:/home/john$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.3 Linux/3.13.0-161-generic
```

Comment: Current version of awscli is 1.16.52. I don't think you can safely use apt-get to install awscli. I would uninstall it and follow awscli instructions to use pip or the bundled installer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. Couldn't find the current version info in the docs anywhere in my earlier search.

Comment: I don’t think you’ll find that info in docs. May be best to rely on https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/releases

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. Switching to the latest version as suggested solved the problem. Post your response as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [most recent release of awscli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/releases) is 1.16.x so I would update the awscli and re-test. It's possible that this was fixed (or was unsupported in version 1.2.x, which you are running).

More generally, I don't think you can safely use apt-get to install the latest awscli on Ubuntu. I would uninstall it and follow [awscli instructions for Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux.html) to use pip or the bundled installer.